# Редактирование размера компонента в Битрикс-Сайт

Tags: битрикс, меню, компоненты

Объясните, пожалуйста, как можно отредактировать область компонента в Битриксе. 
Вставил свой див в header:

```
<div id="header">
                <div id="topline" style="background-color: #867550; width: 976px; margin: auto; height: 36px;"></div>
                <div id="topbanner" style="position: relative; left: 10px; margin-bottom: 15px;">
<? $APPLICATION->IncludeFile( '/include/slogan_inc.php', array(),
    array(
        'MODE'  => 'html',
        'TEMPLATE'  => 'page_inc.php',
    )
); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Следом за ним идет компонент с меню:

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:menu", "top", array(
    "ROOT_MENU_TYPE" => "top",
    "MENU_CACHE_TYPE" => "Y",
    "MENU_CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
    "MENU_CACHE_USE_GROUPS" => "Y",
    "MENU_CACHE_GET_VARS" => array(
    ),
    "MAX_LEVEL" => "1",
    "CHILD_MENU_TYPE" => "left",
    "USE_EXT" => "N",
    "ALLOW_MULTI_SELECT" => "N"
    ),
    false
);?>
```

Но при наведение (в режиме правки) на компонент с меню, область самого компонента (не меню) очень сильно расползается вверх. Как бы можно уменьшить размер до размера меню?

Прикладываю скрин:

[image: На картинке видно как сильно выступает поле компонента вверх]

Answer (score 1):

Если расползание области компонента не мешает редактировать его параметры, то такое изменение не важно, так как обычный пользователь не видит этой области.

Можно обернуть Битрикс-компонент в div и стилями этот div править.

Можно скопировать шаблон компонента меню в свой шаблон, и там править его код